# White Screen Appears while Launching App in Google Pixel2 and SamsungGalaxyS6

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have created android apk with ci(jenkins). When i try to install the same apk on Google Pixel2 Or Samsung Galaxy S6 White screen appears for 10-20 seconds then suddelny ANR message appears.

But APK Built from Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 is working fine.

Could anyone help me to figure out the problem.
I have attached the adb logs [here](https://github.com/VIKAS9899/LogRepo/blob/master/Logs/BlankScreenAdbLogs.log)

App Package Name: com.fieldtitan.droid.qa

Comment: Did you test it on other device ?

Comment: Yes, in Other device it is launching successfully

Comment: Try to clean the cache of the two device in system setting .